# Online resource for finding co-working space while traveling

Tags: online-resources, internet

We have a number of questions about finding [coworking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coworking) space in a number of cities. I'm interested in a general resource for finding such places. This may make my question too broad and/or a list question.  My ideal resource would allow searching for cafes/co-working space in a particular city/neighborhood, and would provide for reviews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course! There's the [Coworking Wiki](http://wiki.coworking.org/w/page/16583831/FrontPage)!

And if you'd like a simple directory, they have a [Coworking Directory](http://wiki.coworking.org/w/page/29303049/Directory) indexed by location, and with a map as well.

[There's an iPhone app to find coworking places](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coworking/id400569601).

There's also [Sharedesk](https://www.sharedesk.net/) - which lets you search and book any one of thousands of meeting places world-wide as well.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that existed. It looks like its more focused on shared office spaces than on cafes. Perhaps I should update my question, or ask a second one, specifically about cafes.

Comment: @Flimzy cafes would be an interesting other question. At WDS in Portland we discussed such a site for the Oregon area, perhaps it exists at a bigger scale too.

Comment: [Done.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39821/444).

Comment: Hey, nice! I regret that I have but one upvote to give!