# Online resource for finding cafes/wifi hotspots for working while traveling

Tags: online-resources, internet, work, cafes

Similar to my question asking about [coworking spaces](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39814/444), are there any online resources for finding more temporary work spaces? Specifically, cafés, restaurants, wifi hotspots, etc?

- Internet connectivity

  - Reliability
  - Session limits, if any
  - Security type (WPA2? Open/unencrypted? etc)
  - Any restrictions (ports other than 80 blocked? Transparent proxy? etc)
- Availability of electrical outlets
- Type of environment

  - Tables with chairs vs sofas/lounge area, etc
  - Music/noise type/level
- Food/drink menu and price (if applicable)

Many resources allow public reviews which may contain some or all of this information, but I've yet to find one which actually makes it easy to see this information without just reading through dozens or hundreds of reviews. TripAdvisor, Urban Spoon, Yelp, even Google maps are candidates.

Some of these even mention if wifi is available, but rarely, if ever, mention some aspects of wifi connectivity important to professionals, such as session limits, or if certain ports are blocked. And I've never seen a resource which mentions the availability of electrical outlets.

But is there a wifi indexing site somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

While it won't show ports or limits or tell you much more about the cafe (for now), you can see locations and speeds using [Instabridge](http://instabridge.com/en/).

It shows a map around you with available wifi, the location (eg name of cafe) and the tested speed of the connection.  I've found it a handy quick resource for finding a cafe nearby.

Comment: Man, I thought of creating a similar app to that a while ago.  It seems to already be in effect.  Lemme try this jawnt out and see if I can improve on their shizzle, my nizzle.

Comment: Is Instabridge Android only? Haven't been able to figure that out for sure from their webpage, and I don't have a smartphone of my own.

Comment: iPhone is 'coming shortly', apparently.